# How to include s3image inside ReactJs card

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, semantic-ui

I'm working on a photo sharing app using reactJ hosted on AWS.
Everything works fine but I'm struggling to have some style for images.
Basically I have this piece of code

```
const PhotosList = React.memo((props) => {
    const PhotoItems = (props) => {
      return props.photos.map(photo => {
        return (
                  <S3Image 
                    key={photo.thumbnail.key} 
                    imgKey={'resized/' + photo.thumbnail.key.replace(/.+resized\//, '')}
                    level="private"                            
                  />
        )
      }
      );
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
        <Divider hidden />
        <PhotoItems photos={props.photos} />
      </div>
    );
  })
```

What I'm trying to do is to use `Card` component from react `semantic-ui` to display pictures from S3 and I have no idea how to do it.

I was thinking to have something like from s3image to store values into a map and then iterate over and display the image using Card component. I don't know if this is possible and if so, how to do it.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 0):

if you pass an array of s3 images source as a props you can use the card component like this:

```
const PhotosList = React.memo(props => {
  return props.photos.map(photo => (
    <Card>
      <Image src={photo} wrapped ui={false} />
    </Card>
  ))
})
```

If you need the card to be of same height use the cards element instead to group them together.

Comment: I don't understand how to use key and imgKey

Comment: how are you retrieving the data from s3? can you post your data structure?

Comment: Actually, I managed to wrap the image inside a card. I have added some style to the s3Image.